# Adding unique titles to subplots in matplotlib using a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib

I have 8 subplots which I have created through a for loop, I've managed to add axis labels which was fine because these were identical across all charts. However my titles are different. Can anyone please tell me how to amend my for loop so it iterates through the titles? I have tried ax.set_title(titles) but this just lumps them all together rather than iterating through each one. I've also tried making the titles individual lists within a list but this didn't work either. The data relate to the Insanity Fit Test which is carried out 5 times throughout the Insanity program (in case you were wondering what the x axis was showing). My code is below:

```
     fit_list = [[78.0, 94.0, 108.0, 117.0, 124.0], [40.0, 46.0, 48.0, 50.0, 50.0], [70.0, 90.0, 103.0, 100.0, 111.0], 
    [37.0, 38.0, 44.0, 55.0, 72.0], [5.0, 9.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.0], [11.0, 15.0, 17.0, 18.0, 21.0], 
    [24.0, 30.0, 32.0, 34.0, 36.0], [35.0, 44.0, 50.0, 53.0, 64.0]]
        
        x = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], 
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,]]
        
        y = fit_list
        
        titles = ['Switch kicks', 'Power jacks', 'Power knees', 'Power jumps', 'Globe jumps', 'Suicide jumps', 
'Push up jacks', 'Low plank obliques']
        
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 4, figsize = (20, 10))
        
        for exercise, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
            ax.bar(x[exercise], y[exercise], color = 'red')
            ax.set_xlabel('Fit test event')
            ax.set_ylabel('Number of reps')
        plt.tight_layout()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be the following:

```
for t, exercise in zip(titles, range(8)):
    ax = axes.ravel()[exercise]
    ax.bar(x[exercise], y[exercise], color = 'red')
    ax.set_xlabel('Fit test event')
    ax.set_ylabel('Number of reps')
    ax.set_title(t)
```

[image]